# How to create windows 10 iot core application icon

Tags: windows-10-universal, iot, windows-10-iot-core, windows-iot-core-10

I have created an windows 10 iot core application and i created the app bundle in appx format. That's installing properly in windows 10 machine. But i want to install in IOT core board

The package file which i have created like below:

```
    ABC_1.0.9.0_AnyCPU_Debug.appxbundle
```

I have created through visual studio

Comment: Please improve your question and make it more clear, to raise the chances of getting a good answer

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) to create the the appxbundle.

Then in the [windows iot device portal](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/deviceportal), select add button to install your app like this:

[image]

After that, you will see this Dialog：

[image]

Select browse option to find your app bundle and make sure "I want to specify optional packages" selected like this:

[image]

Add all the dependencies(.appx). If you're building for MinnowBoard Max, they are in `dependencies\x86` path. If you're building for Raspberry Pi 2, Raspberry Pi 3 or the DragonBoard, they are in `dependencies\ARM` folder.

After that, select next will start the install process. After the process is done successfully you can see your app in the apps list of device portal.

Comment: Thanks @Rita Han.   it's useful for me. What about intel joule board

Comment: @impulse Joule board has x64 architecture. So you can select x64 instead of x86 and ARM.