# Please verify that the remote tools are installed correctly on the remote machine

Tags: visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging, windows-iot-core-10

I use Windows IoT 10 Core on Raspberry Pi 3. I develop application on Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

I have long conversation about the problem in an other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723792/failed-to-connect-to-device-192-168-1-17-using-universal-authentication/54739614?noredirect=1#comment96269578_54739614)

I didn't had debugger running on Windows IoT device originally and followed [manual](http://annabooks.com/Articles/Articles_IoT10Core/Windows-10-IoT-Core-Native-Remote-Debug-V1.3.pdf) for copy and start the process.

Now I have follow error:

> 1>------ Deploy started: Project: CurrencyExchange, Configuration:
>   Debug ARM ------
>   1>DEP0110 : Unable to check remote machine
>   '192.168.1.17' for developer mode. Please verify that the remote tools
>   are installed correctly on the remote machine, and that the correct
>   remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings.
>
> ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

**UPDATE**

As Rita Han suggested, I tried to run the process with different account, however it yields error:

```
[192.168.1.17]: PS C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\Documents> Start-Process msvsmon.exe -Credential 'DefaultAccount' -ArgumentList '"/nowowwarn /noauth /anyuser /nosecuritywarn /timeout:36000"'
The parameter '-Credential' is not supported for the cmdlet 'Start-Process' on this edition of Windows.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotInstalled: (:) [Start-Process], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

It important to add, that I'm **actually succeeded to debug remotely before reflashing**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal, no need to copy files like msvsmon.exe etc manually to the remote device and no need to configure the firewall rules for remote debugger. Visual Studio will copy these files when you [remote deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/appdeployment) the first UWP application to the device this path: `C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\appdata\local\DevelopmentFiles\VSRemoteTools\arm`.

> I have long conversation about the problem in an other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723792/failed-to-connect-to-device-192-168-1-17-using-universal-authentication/54739614?noredirect=1#comment96269578_54739614)

I assume you never remote deploy successfully. You can find same error messages with yours on [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search.html?f=&type=question%20OR%20problem%20OR%20idea&type=question%20OR%20problem%20OR%20idea&c=&redirect=search%2Fsearch&sort=relevance&q=Remote%20Debugger%20%28MSVSMON.EXE%29%20does%20not%20appear). You can see that there maybe several reasons for your issue.

My suggestion is (maybe the fastest way) **re-flash the image** because you have made many modifications. And **upgrade your Visual Studio to 2017** because I see your Windows IoT Core version is 17763 from your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723792/failed-to-connect-to-device-192-168-1-17-using-universal-authentication). Then create a new helloworld simple UWP application to try again.

For UWP application you select the Universal Authentication is correct.

And start the remote debugger via device portal is not working because it runs remote debugger under administrator account. While remote debugging from Visual Studio will under DefaultAccount.

Comment: I succeed to debug the process remotely from VS. Unfortunately because of company restrictions I can not to upgrade to VS 2017. I will check your answer as rigth anyway.

Comment: @OlgaPshenichnikova Glad to hear you get it working. Can you share how do you solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I ment, that I actually succeed to debug the program remotely before reflashing the SD card of Raspberry, however after I reflashed the card, the problem isn't able to solve... I sure that if I will use VS 2017 and reflash image again, it will works (this why I checked your solution as working), however I can not to upgrade the VS because of company's policy. Now I write log data to text files and using mocks of hardware controllers.

Comment: @OlgaPshenichnikova **Sorry, I ment, that I actually succeed to debug the program remotely before reflashing the SD card of Raspberry, however after I reflashed the card, the problem isn't able to solve...** What's the version of Windows IoT Core before you reflashed the card.

Comment: It was Windows IoT Core 10, but I have no information now, what build it was... I guess it was something half year old.

Comment: @OlgaPshenichnikova Ok. Thanks for info.

Comment: By the way, I want to check older release of Windows IoT core that will be compatible with VS 2015, but eldest release, I found in Microsoft site is Oct build, and it seems same 17763. Where is elder versions that are compatible with VS 2015?

Comment: @OlgaPshenichnikova Please check "[Previous Windows 10 IoT Core releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/downloads#previous-windows-10-iot-core-releases)".

Comment: I installed old version (Apr 17134), I launch remote debug, the project copied to Raspberry, but I have follow error when debugger try to start: DEP6953 : Failed to launch remote debugger with the following error: 'DEP6953 : Failed to launch remote debugger with the following error: 'Command failed: 0x800705b4'.'.

Comment: OK, I installed Visual Studio 2017, and debug is works.